# Which one is the radius of convergence of this power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of the real variable $x$ of degree $k \geq 1$. Consider the power series $f(z) = \sum_{n=o}^{\infty} p(n)z^n$ where $z$ is a complex variable. Then the radius of convergence of $f(z)$ is

1. $0$
2. $1$
3. $k$
4. $\infty$

the formula is $\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n \to \infty} sup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Here $a_n$ is $p(n)$, but how to apply the formula?please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: A polynomial $p(n) = \sum_{j=0}^k c_j n^j$ of degree $k$ has magnitude less than or equal to $n^k(\sum_j |c_j|)$ for $n \geq 1$. Do you know what $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^k)^{1/n}$ is? Is suffices to know what $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n}$ is

Answer (score 1):

We have $$1\leq |p(n)| \leq (k+1) n^k$$ for sufficiently large $n.$
Hence $$1\leq \sqrt[n]{|p(n)| } \leq \sqrt[n]{k+1}\cdot (\sqrt[n]{n} )^k\to 1$$
so the radius is equal to $1.$

Answer (score 1):

if you use the ration test, you need $$\frac{|p(n+1)||z|}{|p(n)|} < 1 \text{ for large } n$$ for convergence. but we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|p(n+1)|}{|p(n)|} = 1  ,$$  therefore the radius of convergence is $1.$